# Why is my Briggs-Rauscher reaction not oscillating?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, home-experiment

I have been trying to run the Briggs-Rauscher reaction following [this guide](https://chemistrytalk.org/briggs-rauscher-reaction/), which is pretty similar to other guides out there, yet the reaction is failing to not only oscillate, but display any color change whatsoever (although the hydrogen peroxide is visibly reacting and decomposing). I have perfectly followed the guide, so that cannot be the issue. I ran an iodine test on the starch I was using and it reacted, so the issue is not with that. I do not have any silver nitrate to run a chloride test, but all the chemicals come from reputable sellers and do not have any evidence of contamination. (And yes, I used distilled water)

Because of the cold weather and where the chemicals are being stored, the solutions are significantly below room temperature. Could this be the issue? If not, what could I go about doing to try to get the reaction to work?

Comment: Try tweaking the amounts of malonic acid and other reactants, i did this reaction for my high school chemistry project, and it took a bit of trial and error to get it to work. (I used the measurements from NileRed's video.)

Comment: Where i live it's pretty hot, so im also interested as to if temperature messes with things

Comment: Is your source of distilled water reliable? I had an issue with silver nitrate reacting with water in a glass bulb and I had no idea why—turned out the filter we used for our distilled water had stopped working. Also, oscillating reactions are extremely sensitive to impurities—perhaps your glassware isn't clean enough?